# Angular 8 array initialized with HttpClient remains empty

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am trying to initialize an array from a Json file using HttpClient using the folowing code (there is a simple HttpClient service in dr):

```
getData() {
  this.dr.getData().subscribe(data => {
    for (const d of (data as any)) {
      this.ants.push({
        x: d.x,
        y: d.y
      });
    }
    console.log("1st log : " + this.ants);
  });
  console.log("2nd log : " +this.ants);
}
```

The logs give the following result :

```
2nd log : 
1st log : [object Object],[object Object]
```

The array is properly initialized int he first log, but it is executed after the second log, in which the array is empty. I use getData() in ngOnInit(), and I want to use the result (the initialized ant array) in the showData() function:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getData();
  this.ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
  this.showData();
}
```

But like in the 2nd log, the array is empty when executing showData(). Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`subscribe` is asynchronous, it means it wasn't executed at moment when you call `console.log("2nd log : " +this.ants);` (its outside of subscription callback).

If your code depends on the result of `this.dr.getData().subscribe` then move it inside of the callback.